# GoogleMap for IOS is not working in IOS phones

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 5.2.0.0
New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 8.2.0.0

I get this message when I open a map in flutter on iOS simulator and the map shows blank. I have done pod outdated and this error is showing:

> Analyzing dependencies
> The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
> <green>  - Will be updated to the newest version
> <blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of
> specified version in Podfile
> <red>    - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

The following pod updates are available:

- GoogleMaps 5.2.0 -> 5.2.0 (latest version 8.2.0)

I am not able to figure this out. Please provide me some suggestions.

I tried running command pod update and after that pod install but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any errors you are seeing the console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are using flutter, did you properly set the API key on the iOS folder?